# What is the best practice for testing two methods that perform similar but inverted operations?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, testing, xunit

As a hobby project I'm building an app in .NET / C# that takes a bitmap, performs some operation, and saves the modified bitmap. Apart from the modification, this requires methods for turning the bitmap into an array and vice versa. For example:

```cs
interface IBitmapConverter {

    [,]float BitmapToGrayscale(Bitmap bitmap);
    Bitmap GrayscaleToBitmap([,]float grayscale);
}
```

Now say I wanted to create a test for `BitmapToGrayscale`. This test would perform the following steps:

1. Create a very simple bitmap from some known data
2. Call the SUT method (i.e. `BitmapToGrayscale`) to create an array of floats
3. Verify if the contents of the array match the known data

The problem here lies in step 1. How do I construct a bitmap from known data (i.e. in the form of an array of floats)? I could use the other SUT method (i.e. `GrayscaleToBitmap`), but this feels a bit off. I could write a helper method in the test class, but this would basically be a duplication of `GrayscaleToBitmap`. I could work with a known bitmap that I read from a file, but this  feels a bit cumbersome.

Any suggestions on how to do this properly?

Comment: You could use actual images on that you extract the known initial state, then a second one that you compare to the result to verify the output. Each test can use a different result image for comparison.

Comment: Why not just assert that `bitmap == GrayscaleToBitmap(BitmapToGrayscale(bitmap))`? That's pretty common practice when you want to test an invertible operator.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem here lies in step 1. How do I construct a bitmap from known data (i.e. in the form of an array of floats)?

Just create a small bitmap and use [SetPixel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) to set the color.

You will need to specify how the mapping from color values to floats should be done. Is white mapped to 1? 255? How about green? Transparent? This all needs to be part of the specification. You should also specify behavior for all the [pixel formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), and write tests as required.

The same way applies to the reverse. Float has a far larger range than the common pixel formats. So you will need likely need to squish down 32 bits of data into 8 bits. Do you use a linear mapping between 0 and 1? between min and max values in the image? Some type of non linear mapping?

Depending on your choices the round tripping may or may not replicate the original. You may also need to be careful if you want bit perfect round tripping.

I would also consider if a multi dimensional array is the best representation for an image. It stores values in column-major order, the reverse from just about all image formats. So you either need to live with indexing like `image[y,x]`, or transpose the data whenever you are doing any conversions.

Comment: Creating a small bitmap and using SetPixel is _an_ implementation of `GrayscaleToBitmap`, so that would either mean duplicating code, or doing `Assert.Equal(BitmapToGrayscale(GrayscaleToBitmap(grayscale)), grayscale)`, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Of course you are right about needing a detailed specification, but for the sake of this question, let's assume that is all covered.

Comment: @JanHeindeJong, No, it would not be an implementation of `GrayscaleToBitmap`, since SetPixel take *color* values, not floats. If you want to test more esoteric pixel formats you might to access the pixel data directly to set specific values. But in any case, there would be little functional overlap between this code and your `GrayscaleToBitmap`.

Comment: Hmm... my current (rudimentary) implementation uses `SetPixel(x, y, new Color((int)val, (int)val, (int)val))`; where I iterate x and y over the 2D bitmap. Isn't that pretty much what you are suggesting?

Comment: @JanHeindeJong No, because you should test your `BitmapToGrayscale` for non-grayscale colors. All primary colors, as well as transparent, white, and black would be a good place to start. And just casting values is not a good way to convert between precisions in the first place.